# Adding Armadillo to Qt project

Tags: c++, qt, gcc, linker, armadillo

I am trying to run a test for the Armadillo library (5.2) which I have downloaded and I have uncommented the lines `ARMA_USE_LAPACK` and `ARMA_USE_BLAS` in the `config.hpp` file as recommended for Windows [here](http://choorucode.com/2013/11/15/how-to-use-armadillo-on-windows/) . I have set the .pro file as such

```
QT       += core

QT       -= gui

TARGET = armatest
CONFIG   += console
CONFIG   -= app_bundle

TEMPLATE = app

SOURCES += \
    main.cpp

INCLUDEPATH += C:\Armadillo\include

LIBS += -LC:\Armadillo\lib_win64
    -llapack_win64_MT
    -lblas_win64_MT
```

Considering that `lapack_win64_MT.lib` and `blas_win64_MT.lib` are the libraries located in `C:\Armadillo\lib_win64\`

The error I keep on receiving is

```
undefined reference to 'dgetrf_'
undefined reference to 'ddot_'
undefined reference to 'dgemv_'
```

etc. as if I am not linking the libraries properly. What am I missing?

I am using MinGW 4.9.1 as a compiler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was due to two reasons

The libraries were x64 and my compiler was 32-bit (even though my machine is x64)

The LIBS path had to be written with backslashes

```
LIBS += \
    -LC:\Armadillo\lib32 \
    -lliblapack \
    -llibblas
```

Answer (score 2):

You are missing LAPACK and BLAS to supply the actual underlying linear algebra operations.

This is documented in the [Armadillo FAQ](http://arma.sourceforge.net/faq.html) among other places. You may need to reinstall or rebuild Armadillo for your system; it does not ship with LAPACK and BLAS.

My preferred approach would be to build a standalone Armadillo test program (and maybe you already have), build one for Qt -- and then tried to join the build instructions.

*Edit:* You are falling for the common problem of mixing MinGW and VC++.  The Armadillo site clearly says

> As a courtesy, the Armadillo package contains pre-compiled 64 bit versions of LAPACK and BLAS, as well as MSVC project files to compile the example programs. The MSVC project files were tested on 64 bit Windows 7 with Visual C++ 2012. You may need to make adaptations for later versions of Windows and/or the compiler.

which does not help you with MinGW. You need to find yourself MinGW's compiled LAPACK and BLAS.

Comment: Actually I have downloaded Armadillo with the LAPACK and BLAS library included. I have followed all the steps suggested in the link I have posted, I don't think there is the need to actually install Armadillo, but maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: Hm. I never use it standalone on Windows so maybe it does come with the libraries.   What you need to check, though, is that Qt and Armadillo expect the same compiler.

Comment: Updated my answer -- your problem is indeed the mix of VC++ and MinGW.  You need to find yourself MinGW's compiled LAPACK and BLAS.

Comment: OK, I am slowly resolving the issue. Although my machine is 64 bit, Mingw is 32 bit so I was loading the wrong libraries. I managed to make it work through Code::blocks loading the 32-bit libraries for lapack and blas. On qt creator though I still have the same error even if I changed the libraries (and I am using the same compiler of codeblocks!).